# Calculate the integral on a closed, smooth curve.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\oint \limits_C (7y+x+2)dx+(5+y+2x)dy$$ where the curve C is the circle: $(x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2=25$.
This integral calls for Green's Theorem.

$$\iint \limits_D-5dydx$$ I beleive the region D is best represented in polar. Is it correct to write the region like this $r=2a\cos(\theta)+2b\sin(\theta)$? Then the bounds are as such $\{(r,\theta) \mid 0<r<2a\cos(\theta)+2b\sin(\theta), 0<\theta<2\pi\}$

$$\text{So,}\oint \limits_C (7y+x+2)dx+(5+y+2x)dy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2a\cos(\theta)+2b\sin(\theta)}-5r\ drd\theta$$

Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate this double integral geometrically:  It is the signed volume of a cylinder with height $-5$ and base of radius $5$, so has volume $-5(\pi(5)^2) =-125\pi$.

Alternatively, you could evaluate the integral in polar as you propose.  Your proposed parameterization of the circle is incorrect however.  You can write any point in this shifted circle as $(x,y) = (a+rcos(\theta),b+r\sin(\theta))$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Isn't the circle with center (a,b) given by the equation $r=2a\cos(\theta)+2b\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Something has to be wrong because you do not even have an $r$ in there.

Comment: I see where your going at, its clear that the radius here is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. So there seems to be a dependency of the center on the radius. Is there a more general polar equation for the circle?

Comment: I think that you are really pretty lost here.  It might be better to sit down with someone who can work with you face to face.  The integral you seek is just $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^5 -5rdrd\theta$$.

Comment: If you assume that r=5, you are saying that the circle, region D, is centered at zero--which is not true. In this case, it doesn't make a difference because D is bounded by C if r=5. I was asking a general question about circles and polar equations.

Comment: I am not assuming the circle is centered at $0$.  It is hard to see that in this case because the integrand is constant, but in general the center of the circle would be taken care of by transforming the integrand, not the region of integration.  Generally if D((a,b),s) is the disk of radius $s$ centered at $(a,b)$ , $$\iint_{D((a,b),s)} f(x,y)dxdy = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^s f(T(r,\theta))rdrd\theta$$ where $T(r,\theta) = (a+r\cos(\theta),b+r\sin(\theta))$.

Comment: In your case $f$ was the constant $-5$, so precomposing with $T$ didn't change anything.

Comment: In other words, when you do a polar integral, you are always essentially recentering your region of integration at the origin.